# 2 Different Costs in Multivariate Linear Regression due to Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I started out my ML journey, taking Andrew Ng's Machine learning course on Coursera, and tried to implement Multivariate Linear Regression using Python. However, I'm facing a lot of trouble parsing the data and converting it into a proper working Numpy array. There seems to be so many Numpy functions that perform the same type of processing on the data, that it's hard to figure which function does what. The major problem cause of this is that it affects the algorithm that I'm running.

When I implement the code using `np.matrix()` to convert the data into a Numpy matrix I get a Cost function of **2064911681.6185248**. I get the same Cost function when I use `np.values` instead of `np.matrix()`. However, every python solution for this problem online, gets a cost function of **2105448288.629247** using `np.newaxis` for X and Y. Whenever, I try to use `np.newaxis` I get a `Type Error` saying `Key is Invalid`.

My question is, why does parsing the data in different ways give different cost functions, even though the data shape is how I want it to be? I've provided my Code below. Is there a single efficient and correct way to convert the data into Numpy arrays?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

#Load the data

data = pd.read_csv("ex1data2.txt", header=None, names=["Size", "No. of Bedrooms","Price"])
print(data.head(),"\n")

#Initialize columns and size of dataset
cols = data.shape[1]
m = data.shape[0]
theta = np.matrix(np.zeros(cols))
ones = np.ones((m,1))

#Initializing Parameters
alpha = 0.01
iters = 400
cost_list = np.zeros(iters)

#Setting X and Y
X = np.matrix(data.iloc[:,:cols-1])
Y = np.matrix(data.iloc[:,cols-1:])

#Feature Scaling and Adding Ones to X
X = (X - np.mean(X)) / np.std(X)
X = np.hstack((ones, X))

print(f"X Shape: {X.shape} \nY Shape: {Y.shape} \nTheta Shape: {theta.shape} \n")

#Defining Algorithms
def hypothesis(X, theta):
    h = np.dot(X, theta.T)
    return h

def cost_function(X, Y, theta, m):
    squared_error = np.power((hypothesis(X, theta) - Y) , 2)
    J = np.sum(squared_error) / (2*m)
    return J

def gradient_descent(X, Y, theta, m, alpha, iters):
    for i in range(iters):
        error = hypothesis(X, theta) - Y
        temp = np.dot(error.T, X)
        theta = theta - ((alpha/m) * temp)
        cost_list[i] = cost_function(X, Y, theta, m)

    return theta, cost_list

#Printing Initial and Final Values
print(f"Inital Theta = {theta}")
print(f"Inital Cost = {cost_function(X, Y, theta, m)}")

new_theta, cost_list = gradient_descent(X, Y, theta, m, alpha, iters)

print(f"Final Theta = {new_theta}")
print(f"Final Cost = {cost_function(X, Y, new_theta, m)}")

#Plotting Cost vs Iterations
plt.plot(cost_list, color="Red", label="Cost")
plt.xlabel("Iterations")
plt.ylabel("Cost")
plt.title("Cost vs Iterations")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Using `np.matrix` is generally a bad idea, `np.array` is usually preffered.

Comment: np.array doesn't seem to work. It causes the cost function to increase.